# My media queries is not working properly especially of landscape

Tags: html, css, media

I am working on media queries for one Header, but the media queries is not working. If I fix the media query for one device correctly then it is not working on my device.
Here is my code...

```
@media (max-width: 499px) {
    .mission h1 {
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .mission h2 {
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #p1 {
        font-size: 6px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    #p2 {
        font-size: 5px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 610px) {
    .mission h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .mission h2 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #p1 {
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    #p2 {
        font-size: 7.5px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .mission h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .mission h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #p1 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    #p2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .mission h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .mission h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #p1 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    #p2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
}
@media tv and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .mission h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .mission h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #p1 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    #p2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 860px) {
    .mission h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        ;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .mission h2 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #p1 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    #p2 {
        font-size: 8px;
        margin-right: 540px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
}
```

The above code that I tried solved my problem a little bit, because it is not responding exactly what I want. 
My website is live and it can be sacked online by using the link.
http://www.ericsbo.se/
I normally check my website for responsiveness by this website website online. If any one check that can find some bugs. The online checking website can be find here http://www.isresponsive.com/

Comment: Have you tried setting a max-width limit on the ones with only a min-width?
For example `@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 800px)`

Comment: yes i did that.. I will try again.

Comment: Read answer for more involved response.

Comment: Thanks a lot,, it was great information. I applied that. now the only issue is with landscape.

Comment: You're welcome :)

If my answer was correct to your intent, please accept it as the correct answer (click the check mark to the left of my answer).

Comment: Can you please check the site for landscape? I am very thankful to you. Thanks a lot. What should I do to make it OK for landscapte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have done some testing and I know ***why*** it is doing it because max-width means, "If the [width] is less than or equal to [max-width] return true".

Knowing this we read the query like this:

`is 300px <= 499px (returns true)`

`is 300px <= 800px (returns true)`

So in this case both will return true and I believe in CSS the latter code will have greater priority and will overrule the previous code. So, you can switch this and accomplish it with min-width, set boundaries (what I suggested in comments) or I believe if you put the `min-width:499px` logical statement **AFTER** the `min-width:800px` logical statement it ***should*** work.

EDIT:
For landscape, I guess the best way that I can think about (I haven't done this in a while) would be to assign the logical statement to everyone you don't want to run while it is in landscape mode `and not (orientation: landscape)` so it won't be trigger. Probably a better way, but you have to do some research. Here is a nice page with some good information.
[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and concluded that the most accurate media queries which cover almost all media devices are following.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px) {
/****** @Style ******/
{

@media only screen and (min-width: 761px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    /****** @Style ******/
}
```